# Change EC2 Region - AMI not showing up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 machine running on a wrong region, so for change it, I created a image of that instance, and copied that image to the new region. So now, I should launch an EC2 instance using that image, is that correct?
The problem is the copy image is not showing up as an option for creating from an AMI. However, if I go to launch a machine on the original region, the original AMI I created shows up as an option. So only the copy didn't showed up. I checked the status and it's completed. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In the target region, in the console, on the left side navigation pane, under Images, click AMI.  Is your copied AMI listed here?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I didn't. I had a snapshot but not the image. If you wanna post the answer, all I had to do is to click right-button and select "Create Image" from the snapshot, as a HVM and it worked!

Comment: @RonanLopes If you found solution, just add it as answer and accept it.

Comment: @RonanLopesas as kosa suggested, accept your answer so it will be helpful for someone else.

Comment: @RumeshEranga sure! As soon as passed the 2 days required, I'll accept it! Thank you =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my answer: apparently, on the new region I had the snapshot but not the image (AMI), so from the snapshot I created it (right-click button -> create image). In my case, used HVM type option. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

As you figure, **AMI exists only in a region**

That is the main reason that if you go to AWS marketplace or look for existing AMI (see [example](http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/)) you'll find the list of AMI per region, you'll need a specific AMI for the region where you want to launch the ec2 instance.

You can check this [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/aws/ec2-ami-copy-between-regions/) about Cross Region EC2 AMI Copy for the presentation of the feature or read [Copying an AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/CopyingAMIs.html) for the full details

Comment: Thank you, man! I sure will take some time to read it. I got confused about snapshots/images and their differences. Thank you again!